# "Missing argument in parameter list" error while creating .dll file from the .o file

Tags: java, c++, powershell, dll

Am just starting learn jni and decided to do a hello world. i created a helloworld java file whose code is

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public native void displayHelloWorld();
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("hello");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new HelloWorld().displayHelloWorld();
    }
    
}
```

and i compiled it to get the following header file

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class HelloWorld */

#ifndef _Included_HelloWorld
#define _Included_HelloWorld
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     HelloWorld
 * Method:    displayHelloWorld
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_displayHelloWorld
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

followed by creating a c file whose code is

```
#include<jni.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_HelloWorld_displayHelloWorld(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    printf("Hello World \n");
    return;
}
```

and compiled it to create the  helloworld.o file

and now when i tried to create the .dll file using the command

`gcc -shared -o hello.dll HelloWorld.o -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias`

i get this error

```
At line:1 char:42
+ gcc -shared -o hello.dll HelloWorld.o -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias
+                                          ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

what am i missing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204105/tdm-gccs-mingw32-gcc-throws-missing-argument-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in PowerShell comma has a special meaning of [comma operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#comma-operator-) unlike, e.g., in Bash, where in such context there is no any special meaning to it. When your command is parsed, `-Wl` is considered a parameter name and `,` is interpreted to form an array (parameter list) as its argument. As seen in linked documentation, `,` is necessarily *binary* operator unless in expression mode, whereas for command invocation [argument mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.2#argument-mode) is used. But there's no left argument for this comma, thus `Missing argument in parameter list` error.

To solve this, you can change the command to make PowerShell stop intepreting `,` in a special way by making `-Wl,--add-stdcall-alias` a quoted string using  [one of the types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2) of strings. For our simple case any string type would do, e.g. with single-quoted strings we have:

```
gcc -shared -o hello.dll HelloWorld.o '-Wl,--add-stdcall-alias'
```

Another option is to use [stop parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.2#the-stop-parsing-token) `--%`:

```
gcc --% -shared -o hello.dll HelloWorld.o -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias
```